# Pointer address as reference in function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've got one general question, why can't I pass the the pointer's address as a reference?

```
void domdom(string &foo)
{
 foo = "";
}

string fooso = "blabal";
string* p_fooso = fooso;

domdom(p_fooso); // <-- why is that not possible? And what should I pass to be able to modify foosoo?
```

I know I could change the function `domdom` to accept `(string* foo)`, but is it also possible to modify the `string fooso` in the function by using the pointer to it and the given function?

Comment: `string* p_fooso = fooso;` is an error; check your compiler output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why can't i pass the the pointer's address as a reference?

Because that's how the language is defined.

Instead, you can dereference the pointer to get a reference to the string:

```
domdom(*p_fooso);
```

or, pass the actual object directly:

```
domdom(fooso);
```

---

Also note that `string* p_fooso = fooso;` doesn't compile. You have to write `string* p_fooso = &fooso;`.

Comment: thanks, I thought the reference saves the address as well as the pointer does in the same way.

Comment: @Ammy The reference *does* save the address internally, but it is used in a very different way, so the two are intentionally made non-interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare p_fooso as a string reference type. 
You might want to rename variable as r_fooso!

```
string& r_fooso=fooso;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers and references are similar under the hood, but are used differently, which is why mixing them by implicit conversion is not allowed by C++, to avoid confusion.

However you can always explicitly convert a reference to a pointer, and vice versa, *without* incurring the overhead of a copy. For example, if you call the function as `domdom(*p_fooso)`, you *will* get the desired effect, i.e. the function will receive reference to the exact object you'd get by dereferencing the pointer.